# Creating an "update.zip" for install an APK from Recovery Mode (Bootloader)?

Tags: android, installation, apk, recovery, bootloader

I'm researching about how to create an "update.zip" file for install the APK or APKs from Android Recovery Mode (Bootloader).

I found this topic in XDA, using a script we can create the "update.zip" file: "**[Update.zip 2.0 Modifier/Creator [Script] Drag/Drop Support [Windows]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=717437)**", the actual download for the script is: http://www.mediafire.com/?22o6ez2pvav5eoa (updated in the page 27, comment #261).

And here a video of how to use this simple script: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i0KzFPMA6-8

But, I tried it for just a one APK (in the two ways) and the "recovery mode" always got me  "signature verification failed".

Any idea of how to create an "update.zip" correctly for an APK?

Comment: Is this a rooted phone? Do you have ClockworkMod? The build of ClockworkMod that I have on my phone allows me to temporarily disable signature verification. It's under "install zip from sdcard -> toggle signature verification".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a recovery image that does *not* have an option to disable signature verification, make sure to flash one that *can* disable signature verification.